# Extra values when parsing, then looping through a JSON String

Tags: javascript, json

So, I have a JSON string, and I intend to parse it, and alert the contents, like so.

```
var json_string = '[1,2,3,4,5]';
var parsed_string = JSON.parse(json_string);
for(x in parsed_string) alert(x)
```

However, not only do I get the five elements, I get a whole bunch of extra crud I didn't ask for... $constructor, $family, append, associate, etc...

Is there any way I can iterate through this array without hitting these extra values?

**Edit**: For those wondering - I later realized that parsed_string.length returns the proper array length for me to iterate over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for in` loops over all enumerable object properties; which in the case of an array in Javascript, is all elements, and all methods/ attributes you've added to the array instance, or to any object in the prototype chain.

This is the one single reason you should use `for ;;;` for looping through arrays.

```
var json_string = '[1,2,3,4,5]';
var parsed_string = JSON.parse(json_string);
for(var i=0;i<parsed_string.length;i++) alert(parsed_string[i]);
```

Comment: Hey Matt - thanks for the quick reply. I've been coding in PHP too long, and have gotten too comfortable with foreach(). :)

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through a JavaScript object like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

`.hasOWnProperty()` ensures that the property specified by `key` is not inherited. However, you're dealing with an array here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```